# how to assign char to string?

Tags: c#, string, char

I have a `string` `Lat` that has word in it, and I want to store it's last letter in a new `string`, but it gives me an error: `"cannot implicitly convert "char" to string"`

```
current =Lat[j];
```

My `current` is a `string`, when I try to use `#.ToString`, it gives me another error:  `Cannot convert method group 'ToString' to non-delegate type 'string'. Did you intend to invoke the method?`

Comment: What is declaration of current var? Is it string?

Comment: from the question, @Jacek `current` is a `string` and so is `Lat`. `Lat[j]` gives a unicode character. hence the compiler gives the error

Comment: Why not use String.Substring(int,int)? MSDN: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aka44szs.aspx

Comment: This error:  `Cannot convert method group 'ToString' to non-delegate type 'string'. Did you intend to invoke the method?` is because you **forgot** to make `.ToString` a method, like so:  `.ToString()`.  I will edit the post accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

Simplest way is

```
current = Lat[j].ToString();
```

or

```
current = Lat.Substring(Lat.Length - 1);
```

but it's a bit odd to access a string by it's indexer - if you post more code there may be a cleaner way to get you want you need.

Answer (score 0):

use `#.ToString()` method to convert it to a string.

like this: `current = Lat[j].ToString()`

Answer (score 0):

either
`current =Lat[j].ToString();`

OR declare current as a char anyway (Can't tell from your usage if this is a good idea)

Answer (score 0):

If you want the last character in your string, use `System.Linq` to retrieve the last letter.

```
string newString = original.Last().ToString();
// original.Last() gives you a char
// .ToString function after changes it to a string.
```